# Which question should be asked?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am not used to StackExchange (I just stumbled upon the committing phase for this group because a friend of mine who knows I am a math fan told me about it), so I am not really sure which kind of questions should be made (at least from people in the private beta).

For example, I think that asking a question about Pick Theorem or Benford Law could be interesting, not for me since I already know the answer but for prospective readers. What should I do? Just write the question and let other people answer it? For me, writing question and answer, besides being a bit of cheating, seems to be useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are calling questions of this type "seeded questions". It is ok to ask them and answer them yourself. It is for the good of the site, so that there are many good examples when the site goes public.

Comment: If you can ask a seeded question that is a well-written question, then you should do as many as you can before the site goes public.

Comment: I will add that it is good to let it sit for a bit, and then go ahead and answer, just because if someone knows the answer they will have fun writing it.

Comment: I don't guarantee my questions are well written, unfortunately.